# How to write the Java code for Json array inside json array in JSON parsing in android

Tags: android, json

How to write the code for Json array inside json array in JSON parsing in android?

I have a problem with writing functionality of following json parsing.. Please anybody can help me for code in android?

my json data is

```
{
  "error": "0",
  "message": "List of all instances",
  "instance_list": [
    [
      {
        "instance_uid": "1046",
        "last_message": "",
        "message_id": "m-563-1046-1442486965",
        "msg_dir": "outgoing",
        "order_id": "5",
        "DishID": "",
        "seller_uid": "",
        "instance_name": "",
        "login_user_image": ""
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "instance_uid": "1046",
        "last_message": "",
        "message_id": "m-563-1046-1442486965",
        "msg_dir": "outgoing",
        "order_id": "5",
        "DishID": "",
        "seller_uid": "",
        "instance_name": "",
        "login_user_image": ""
      }
    ]
{
        "1": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message9 with orderid",
            "message_id": "m-563-477-1442334018",
            "msg_dir": "outgoing",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        },
        "2": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message9 with orderid",
            "message_id": "m-563-477-1442333953",
            "msg_dir": "outgoing",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        },
        "3": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message9 with orderid",
            "message_id": "m-563-477-1442333861",
            "msg_dir": "outgoing",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        },
        "4": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message9 with orderid",
            "message_id": "m-477-563-1442333831",
            "msg_dir": "incoming",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        },
        "5": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message9 with orderid",
            "message_id": "m-477-563-1442333249",
            "msg_dir": "incoming",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        },
        "6": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message9 with orderid",
            "message_id": "m-563-477-1442302909",
            "msg_dir": "outgoing",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        },
        "7": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message9 with orderid",
            "message_id": "m-563-477-1442302748",
            "msg_dir": "outgoing",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        },
        "8": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message9 with orderid",
            "message_id": "m-563-477-1442302439",
            "msg_dir": "outgoing",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        },
        "9": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message8 with orderid",
            "message_id": "m-477-563-1442300668",
            "msg_dir": "incoming",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        },
        "10": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message7 with orderid",
            "message_id": "m-477-563-1442300657",
            "msg_dir": "incoming",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        },
        "11": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message6 with orderid",
            "message_id": "m-477-563-1442300645",
            "msg_dir": "incoming",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        },
        "12": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message5 with orderid",
            "message_id": "m-477-563-1442300633",
            "msg_dir": "incoming",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        },
        "13": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message4 with orderid",
            "message_id": "m-477-563-1442300620",
            "msg_dir": "incoming",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        },
        "14": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message3 with orderid",
            "message_id": "m-477-563-1442300608",
            "msg_dir": "incoming",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        },
        "15": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message2 with orderid",
            "message_id": "m-477-563-1442300596",
            "msg_dir": "incoming",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        },
        "16": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message1 with orderid2",
            "message_id": "m-477-563-1442300575",
            "msg_dir": "incoming",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        },
        "17": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message with orderid1",
            "message_id": "m-477-563-1442300555",
            "msg_dir": "incoming",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        },
        "18": {
            "instance_uid": "477",
            "last_message": "this is test message with orderid",
            "message_id": "m-477-563-1442300535",
            "msg_dir": "incoming",
            "order_id": "1",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "android",
            "login_user_image": "http://sgappstore.com/not86/sites/default/files/styles/chat_user_94_x_94/public/1442298004.jpg?itok=iYaE3w-o"
        }
    },

[
        {
            "instance_uid": "183",
            "last_message": "this is android test message",
            "message_id": "m-463-464-1441088232",
            "msg_dir": "outgoing",
            "order_id": "0",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "",
            "login_user_image": ""
        },
        {
            "instance_uid": "183",
            "last_message": "Hello how are you",
            "message_id": "m-512-513-1441042356",
            "msg_dir": "incoming",
            "order_id": "0",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "",
            "login_user_image": ""
        },
        {
            "instance_uid": "183",
            "last_message": "Hello how are you",
            "message_id": "m-512-513-1441040916",
            "msg_dir": "incoming",
            "order_id": "0",
            "DishID": "",
            "seller_uid": "",
            "instance_name": "",
            "login_user_image": ""
        }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: what problem? where you hanged? any error? where is your code? what you tried?

Comment: Please provide some more information what you have done so far,And read "How to ask?"

Comment: My problem is I am not getting those data from json parsing.. i think my code is something wrong